# Pear Auth or LiveUser

Tags: php, authentication, pear

I can't decide which to use, they both look pretty similar. It's for a shopping cart script, so it has to be quite secure, what thinks you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LiveUser when you need different roles and ACL. Use Auth when you just need some authentication of users without much fuss.